# Ubuntu 12.04.1 becomes unresponsive and frozen

Tags: 12.04, firefox, javascript, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I have a "classic" install of ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64 bits, with the ubuntu-restricted extras 57 installed. All updates done.

When loading this page from a daily news papers from Firefox 18:

http://www.leparisien.fr/societe/video-la-lecon-de-conduite-sur-neige-de-bernard-darniche-20-01-2013-2496573.php

The whole system becomes unresponsive and like frozen.

I can't break it nor gain control again through the: ctrl alt del.

I have to turn it off the hard way (electric reset!).

I suspect a bad javascript on the page.

- Is there a better way to gain control back?
- Is there a better combination of keys to kill the unresponsive application?
- Is this a firefox or an ubuntu bug to report?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No idea about the cause - did you try with another browser (eg. Chromium)? I just opened it in Chromium - system load increased dramatically.

Comment: Just installed Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52. The page loads fine and Ubuntu 12.04.1 is responsive. Looks like a Mozilla Firefox or an Adobe Falsh issue isn't it? But I am still interested in knowing how to kill the dirty app or process that is freezing the machine.

Comment: It seems so - report it as a firefox bug.

Comment: Just reported it to Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

- One method (nearly as extreme as shutting off): <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>SysReq</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>  restarts the X Server (and kills your complete session of course)
- If you are able to open a terminal session (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
  try `pkill firefox` or even `pkill -9 firefox`.
- If you are able to open a *virtual terminal* (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>)
  you can login there (you don't see any feedback when typing your password), and then you can use `pkill` like above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. (ctrlaltT) brought the terminal window on top but I couldn't type anything, the system (display) is frozen. Even the mouse cursor doesn't move anymore.